# Managing multiple realms in a single keycloak admin client application

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-admin-cli

I have a keycloak server with multiple realms(tenants). I am creating a backend spring-boot application to manage the users and their roles (like adding/deleting/editing users,roles etc.) with keycloak-admin-client. Can someone advise me on how can I manage multiple realms/tenants in one single application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multitenancy using Keycloak and SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945198/multitenancy-using-keycloak-and-springboot)

Comment: Thanks.But unfortunately this is not what i am looking for. I am looking for usage of keycloak-admin-client implementation with multitenancy, whereas the above one is about keycloak-adapter